# Pointer variable assignment has copied partial memory when using multithread

Tags: c++, multithreading, gcc

I'm trying to make multithread c++ program.
I've been testing my program for long time, and sometimes got SIGSEGV (segmentation fault).
And I found a pointer variable copied partial memory only, not all.

Here is parts of my code.

**Class definition**

```
class Message
{
    public:
        Message() {}
        virtual ~Message() {}

        virtual void execute() = 0; //do something...
}

class Job
{
    public:
        Job();
        ~Job();

        void post(Message *message);
        void execute(Message *message);

    private:
        Message *_queue[1024] = {nullptr,};
        volatile int _head = 0;
        int _tail = 0;
};
```

And 4 of threads were running and call method of same Job class instance.

**Thread 1 call this method.**

```
void Job::execute(Message *message)
{
    if (message != nullptr)
    {
        int index = __sync_fetch_and_add(&_head, 1) % 1024;
        _queue[index] = message;
    }

    while (_tail != _head)
    {
        int index = _tail % 1024;
        Message *workingMessage = _queue[index];
        while (workingMessage == nullptr)
        {
            sched_yield();
            workingMessage = _queue[index];
        }

        workingMessage->execute();
        _queue[index] = nullptr;
        ++_tail; //this is changed on Thread 1 only!
    }
}
```

**Thread 2~4 call this method.**

```
void Job::post(Message *message)
{
    int index = __sync_fetch_and_add(&_head, 1) % 1024;
    _queue[index] = message;
}
```

After several minutes, I've got SIGSEGV crash on this part of Thread 1.

```
        workingMessage->execute();  // Crash!
```

On debugger, workingMessage had only some part of _queue[Index] value.
For example,

```
_queue[index] : 0x7fffdc09abdb
workingMessage : 0xffdc09abdb
```

or

```
_queue[index] : 0x7fffe8048e35
workingMessage : 0x7fffe8040000
```

like these cases.
I've tried to use std::atomic< Message *> for _queue and workingMessage, same crashes were happened.

What's wrong? I've compiled and tested this on CentOS 7, gcc 4.8.5.

Comment: `_queue[index] = message` is not atomic. I'm guessing that's the problem. But no-one can tell for sure without a full compilable example - a [MCVE] - which you are required to provide for this question to be considered on-topic.